# Failed to install Arch Linux 201804

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I' m trying to install Arch Linux to my disk, and created USB installer with rufus. But when I tried to start from the USB, it failed with description:
    ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201804' device did not show up after 30 seconds...
Then the bash drop into a "[rootfs ]" command line which (seemingly) ooperates fine.
I 've made sure the name of the USB installer is "ARCH_201804", but the error still occured.
How can I fix the problem? Please help.

Comment: I've tried in the past with `2018.3` and it didn't work...ever. I switched and used [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) and everything worked! Try that one...

Comment: Tried. No luck.

Comment: I've seen this over and over. Rufus creates unbootable media a lot of the time. Never the less the Arch Wiki mentions it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media and that you should use DD image mode when copying.